# Trouble with LibreOffice Calc JRE

Tags: java, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm brand new to using macros and spreadsheets and am having trouble with LibreOffice Calc recognizing the JRE that I have installed. I've spent a day following advice on this topic on other forums, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm applying to a coding bootcamp and need to complete a task using an Excel spreadsheet, but can't start the fun coding part until I get this installation problem figured out. I currently have 
java version "1.8.0_101" and
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13).

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: First, StackExchange != forum. Second. [su] is more suited for questions regarding software. If you have questions about the macros, that belongs here

Comment: Okay, sorry. What's the proper way to refer to StackExchange, then? Like I said I'm a beginner. Thanks for the tip about Super User, I'll check that out.

Comment: Purely a Q & A site. Reddit, on the other hand, is more of a "forum", where the site is purely for open discussion. Posts here are for concrete answers to specific problems.

Comment: This question has been [answered on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/1116853/libreoffice-macro-does-not-recognize-jre), so it should be closed here.